# ¿Las listas se pasan por referencia en C#?

Tags: c#, lista, paso-por-referencia

Tengo claro que las listas son en realidad punteros hacia direcciones en memoria donde se guardan las variables reales, entonces quería confirmar si se pasan por referencia automáticamente a las funciones. Hice el siguiente código para comprobar la hipótesis:

```
namespace list_test
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static List<int> Mix(List<int> i)
        {
            // mixes a list with i being the list

            int Counter = 0;
            int Random1 = 0;
            int Random2 = 0;
            Random RandomObject = new Random();
            var ItemNumber = i.Count();

            while (Counter < 1000) // change positions 1000 times in the list
            {
                Random1 = RandomObject.Next(0, ItemNumber);
                Random2 = RandomObject.Next(0, ItemNumber);

                while (Random1 == Random2)
                {
                    Random1 = RandomObject.Next(0, ItemNumber);
                    Random2 = RandomObject.Next(0, ItemNumber);
                }

                i[Random1] += i[Random2];
                i[Random2] = i[Random1] - i[Random2];
                i[Random1] -= i[Random2];

                Counter += 1;
            }

            return i;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<int> i = new List<int>();

            for (int a = 1; a <= 5; a += 1)
            {
                i.Add(a);
            }

            Mix(List);

            for (int a = 1; a <= 5; a += 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(a);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

El resultado es la lista mezclada tal y como quedaría al pasarla por referencia a la función Mix. Ya es bastante claro que se pasó por referencia en este ejemplo, pero quisiera comprobar con ustedes si así ocurre naturalmente o hice algo sin darme cuenta que la pasó por referencia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen dia, normalmente cualquier objeto que necesite ser instanciado se pasa por referencia a la funcion por lo que no es necesario retornalo para hacerle modificaciones, en su caso, el objeto definio 5 espacios en la lista con valores consecutivos, al aplicar el metodo mix cada que encontraba una coincidencia con el valor random, el espacio en este caso es remplazado por otro valor, para las variables primitivas cada igualacion se crea una copia y se asigna. adjunto codigo con algunas modificaciones para que se entienda mejor mi explicacion.

```
namespace list_test
{
    internal class Program
    {
 
    static void Mix(List<int> i)//removemos el retunr no es necesario, lo objetos se pasan por referencias
    {
        // mixes a list with i being the list

        int Counter = 0;
        int Random1 = 0;
        int Random2 = 0;
        Random RandomObject = new Random();
        var ItemNumber = i.Count();

        while (Counter < 1000) // change positions 1000 times in the list
        {
            Random1 = RandomObject.Next(0, ItemNumber);
            Random2 = RandomObject.Next(0, ItemNumber);

            while (Random1 == Random2)
            {
                Random1 = RandomObject.Next(0, ItemNumber);
                Random2 = RandomObject.Next(0, ItemNumber);
            }
            //Las variables primitivas si se hace una copia cada que se asignan
            i[Random1] += i[Random2];
            i[Random2] = i[Random1] - i[Random2];
            i[Random1] -= i[Random2];

            Counter += 1;
        }

      //  return i;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> i = new List<int>();

        for (int a = 1; a <= 5; a += 1)
        {
            i.Add(a);
        }

        Mix(i);

        for (int a = 0; a <= 4; a ++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i[a]);

        }
    }

  }
```

}

Aqui encontre un articulo que te puede interesar
https://geeks.ms/etomas/2012/04/23/c-bsico-paso-por-referencia/
Saludos